# Параметры загрузки ядра Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Здравствуйте, сразу оговорюсь новичок в использовании линукса, поэтому прошу выражаться как можно свободнее.

Установил ubuntu с флешки, при запуске компьютера появляется grub меню, в котором выбираю запустить ubuntu, после этого фиолетовый экран(продолжает висеть бесконечно), на некоторых форумах прочитал о проблеме с acpi, и что в grub меню надо открыть параметры загрузки ядра и устанавливать параметры для корректной работы acpi. У меня ноутбук Acer Swift 3(Core i3-6100U, 4gb RAM,  Intel HD Graphics 520).

Примечание: один раз систему удалось запустить указав параметры: (pci=noacpi, acpi=noirq, pnpacpi=off). Очень много гуглил не могу найти хороших источников, буду рад любой помощи. Версия ubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: Если систему всё-таки удалось запустить, то, вероятно, надо выставить те же параметры? В чём конкретно заключается вопрос?

Comment: Что-то мне кажется вы некорректно установили Ubuntu. Мой совет повторить установку при этом быть внимательным при запросе установки Grub.

Comment: ACER TravelMate TMX349-M-37UT, 14", Intel Core i3 6100U, 4Гб, 128Гб SSD, Intel HD Graphics 520 запускается с арчем без проблем. обновляйся на свежую убунту

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобная проблема была на Acer Aspire E3, вылечить получилось следующим образом:

1. Загрузка системы с параметром **acpi=noirq**
2. Редактирую **/etc/default/grub**
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   Меняем 
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   на 
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq" 
   Сохраняю файл.
3. Обновлем параметры загрузчика ***sudo update-grub***
4. Перезагружаемся. После этого загрузка системы не такая "красивая", но включается/выключается без проблем